# How to modify a behavior of `pathlib.Path`?

Tags: python, wrapper, monkeypatching, pathlib

I want `pathlib.Path` to automatically output logs for some destructive commands such as `path.rename(new_path)`.

I made a subclass of `pathlib.Path` with logging functions, and replaced `from pathlib import Path` to `from mylib import MyPath as Path`.
But it does not affect to the existing subclasses of `pathlib.Path` such as `pathlib.WindowsPath`, which is the actual implementation class of path instances.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from mynicelib import MyPath

p = MyPath('/path/to/file')

isinstance(p, MyPath)  # -> False
isinstance(p, Path)  # -> True
type(p)  # -> <class 'pathlib.WindowsPath'>
```

Comment: You can patch `Path.rename` on the fly.  Do `Path.oldrename = Path.rename` so you can still refer to the original.  BTW, I would hardly call `Path.rename` "destructive".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do some monkeypatching:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path.oldrename = Path.rename

def rename(self,b):
    print("Inside my rename")
    self.oldrename(b)

Path.rename = rename

p = Path('./x.c')
p.rename('y.c')
```

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing pathlib is problematic. There are relevant discussions on this topic at:

- [Fixing Subclassing in Pathlib](https://discuss.python.org/t/fixing-subclassing-in-pathlib/8983)
- [Make pathlib extensible](https://discuss.python.org/t/make-pathlib-extensible/3428)

The best workaround for now is:

```
class MyPath(type(pathlib.Path())):
    ...
```

Comment: heh, this is actually a pretty good use-case for dynamic inheritance like this. I'll have to remember it.